# Picker horizontal numérico en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Necesito el siguiente elemento, de forma horizontal para escoger un valor entre:

```
-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Y que el valor seleccionado siempre esté centrado y resaltado de los demás.
 De muchos controles que veo que se publican, todos son de forma vertical. ¿Hay alguno que sea horizontal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe de forma *nativa* el `picker` en horizontal por lo que se tiene que construir.

Tienes la base que necesitas en [este proyecto](https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker) en el que ya hay definido el `HorizontalPicker` con cualquier elemento que le pases.

Más o menos como funciona:

**Dependencias**

```
compile 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:1.1.1'
```

**Utilización**

```
<com.wefika.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker
        xmlns:picker="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.wefika.horizontalpicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
        android:ellipsize="none | start | middle | end | marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="-1"
        picker:values="@array/values"
        picker:dividerSize="@dimen/itemPadding"
        picker:sideItems="@integer/sideItems" />
```

Dónde los valores los lee de un `array` y los otros valores puedes configurarlos cómo quieras.

Comment: Voy a mirar, en su documentación demasiada extensa no es, a ver si el autor se anima a mejorarlo

Answer (score 2):

Me encontrado con esa librería [Android-SnappingRecyclerView](https://github.com/lauw/Android-SnappingRecyclerView)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra manera seria implementar [LinearSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper.html)  en un `RecyclerView` visto en [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134094/recyclerview-horizontal-scroll-snap-in-center)

Answer (score 1):

Como ya lo han mencionado, no existe de manera nativa pero te presento otra librería muy buena a mi parecer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Dependencias:**

```
compile 'me.angrybyte.picker:picker:1.2.0'
```

**Implementación:**

Primero, define la `View` en tu `layout`(No es necesario que agregues todos los atributos, solo las que se acoplan a tus necesidades):

```
<me.angrybyte.numberpicker.view.ActualNumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/actual_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="#FFFF3040"
    app:bar_color="@android:color/white"
    app:bar_width="1dp"
    app:bars_count="26"
    app:controls_color="@android:color/white"
    app:draw_over_controls="true"
    app:draw_over_text="false"
    app:fast_controls_color="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:highlight_color="#FFFF3040"
    app:max_value="100"
    app:min_value="0"
    app:selection_color="#A0FF3040"
    app:show_bars="true"
    app:show_controls="true"
    app:show_fast_controls="true"
    app:show_highlight="true"
    app:show_text="false"
    app:text_color="@android:color/white"
    app:text_size="16sp"
    app:value="50" />
```

Luego, abres tu `activity` y obtienes la `View` y lo adjuntas al `listener`

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnValueChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = DemoActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ActualNumberPicker mPicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
    mPicker = (ActualNumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.actual_picker);
    mPicker.setListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onValueChanged(int oldValue, int newValue) {
    float percent = (float) newValue / (float) (mPicker.getMaxValue() - mPicker.getMinValue());
    Log.d(TAG, "Currently the picker is at " + percent + " percent.");
}

}
```

Aquí está la [documentación](https://github.com/milosmns/actual-number-picker) completa con todos sus atributos muy bien explicados, espero y te sea algo de ayuda.

Comment: Tiene buena pinta, a ver si tengo tiempo en mirarme esas librerias a fondo y decantarme hacia una.